# ValueError at /pembayaran/ ModelForm has no model class specified. Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

#### File *forms.py*

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import pembayaranform

class pembayaran(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        models = pembayaranform()
        fields='all'
```

> TypeError at /pembayaran/
> 'pembayaranform' object is not callable

What should I do?

Comment: Added an answer, if you can share your `forms.py` as well, I can update my answer accordingly

Comment: from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import pembayaranform

class pembayaran(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        models = pembayaranform
        fields='__all__'

Answer (score 0):

In your `forms.py`, specify a `class` field in the form's `Meta` class:

```
class pembayaran(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    class Meta:
        model = MyModelName
    ...
```

In your updated question, your code has `models` instead of `model`.

Comment: @NetaAulya updated my answer. Your code has `models` inside the `Meta` class, instead of `model` (without the `s`)

Comment: object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: You have to update your question with the updated code, and a full traceback of the error